# When connecting to IBM DB2 using DB2 run time client 8.2.2 from Odbcad32 for testing the connection it is showing RC5

Tags: windows, db2, odbc

I went to syswow64, selected odbcad32,added IBM DB2 ODBC driver 8.01.10.812 and configured in system DSN for checking the Host Name is getting connected or not and when i give the database name,username and password it is showing the below error

[image]

And in the Db2 run time client 8.2 it is showing this error in command line processor

[image]

I am connecting to DB2 Entreprise Edition 8.1.10 in the other Server where the database is available

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @data_henrik I wanted to test whether the Db2 present in another server ip is establishing connection with my computer.

Comment: You appear to be using a version of the DB2 client (8.2 Fixpack 10) that was released in 2005, and went out of support in 2009.  What version of DB2 are you trying to connect to, and on what platform?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde I am using Db2 run time client 8.2.2 on windows server 2016

Comment: @Anish That client is certainly not supported on Windows Server 2016, but I'm more interested in the server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde I am connecting to Db2 Entreprise Server Edition 8.1.10